# My Air conditioner suddenly became defective after a power outage

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling

So, these are the symptoms:

1] The big fan outside is taking a lot longer to start.
2] Within 2 minutes of start-up and cooling, it makes a growling/ rattling sound and
3] The power switch to start the AC trips automatically and the whole unit shuts down.

The problem started this morning, after a power outage, when we heard that electricians were repairing connections somewhere in the city.
Until then the AC was running fine. What could be the problem.

Comment: Was the unit turned off then back on rapidly? What is making a growling/rattling sound? "*The power switch to start the AC*", do you mean the circuit breaker?

Comment: @Tester101: The power switch is a [North West Single Phase Motor Starter](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=north+west+single+phase+motor+starter&espv=2&biw=1360&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB-8jT1c_NAhWMv48KHdpiCqwQ_AUIBigB). The big outer fan of the cooling unit. is making a growling sound just prior to the auto cut.

Comment: Let the AC system "rest" for an hour to ensure there's no fluid back-pressure anywhere which happened when the power outage hit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by checking the start capacitor for the fan motor.  If that's starting to go bad, the motor could be drawing high current for too long while trying to start.

Comment: A spike could have punched the dielectric especially on an older one.+